# Formatar número em Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Tenho um app que faz um cálculo e retorna um `float`, tipo `4/2 = 2.00` mas gostaria que neste cálculo mostrasse apenas o `2`, e se o resultado fosse com casas decimais com números diferentes de `0` ele mostrasse os decimais.

Como mostrar um resultado `float` que ignore os zeros desnecessários?

Comment: Lembrando que quando for compilar suportando ambientes 64 bits você não deve utilizar o `float` diretamente. Ao invés disso utilize sempre `CGFloat`. Ele irá definir o scalar correto baseado no ambiente que você estiver executando.

Answer (score 6):

Utilizando **%g** para definir a precisão, faça algo assim:

```objc
float num1 = 2.00;
float num2 = 2.34;

NSLog(@"%g, %g", num1, num2);
```

Saída:

> 2, 2.34

Answer (score 3):

Use a classe [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Ela é mais versátil do que os especificadores de formato do `printf()` e considera configurações do local do usuário, tais como quais caracteres usar para valores fracionários e separação de milhares. Cuidado com o especificador `%g`: além do potencial arredondamento da última casa decimal, ele usa notação científica para números a partir de um milhão.

Veja o código abaixo, considerando que o programa esteja rodando num dispositivo com configuração de local pt_BR:

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [NSNumberFormatter new];
nf.numberStyle = kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
nf.usesSignificantDigits = YES;
nf.maximumSignificantDigits = 15;

NSLog(@"%%g = %g", 2.0);
NSLog(@"NSNumberFormatter = %@", [nf stringFromNumber:@2.0]);

NSLog(@"-----");

NSLog(@"%%g = %g", 2.123456789);
NSLog(@"%%.15g = %.15g", 2.123456789);
NSLog(@"NSNumberFormatter = %@", [nf stringFromNumber:@2.123456789]);

NSLog(@"-----");

NSLog(@"%%g = %g", 1000.0 * 1000.0);
NSLog(@"%%15g = %15g", 1000.0 * 1000.0);
NSLog(@"NSNumberFormatter = %@", [nf stringFromNumber:@(1000.0 * 1000.0)]);
```

A saída é:

```
%g = 2
NSNumberFormatter = 2
-----
%g = 2.12346
%.15g = 2.123456789
NSNumberFormatter = 2,123456789
-----
%g = 1e+06
%15g =           1e+06
NSNumberFormatter = 1.000.000
```

O formatador foi configurado para considerar dígitos significativos, então dígitos *não* significativos, como zeros após o ponto decimal, não são considerados. Veja também como o especificador `%g` lida com precisão para a parte inteira e a parte decimal, bem como seu comportamento de notação científica para valores com mais de seis dígitos para a parte inteira.

Dê uma olhada na [documentação da classe `NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) para ver outras opções de configuração. Por exemplo, você pode configurar como deve ser feito o arredondamento ou desabilitar a separação de milhares.